# add image beside woocommerce product description in tab

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to place an image next to the product description in the tabs of woocommerce. The code I am trying to use is this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_template_product_description', 'badge', 25);
        function badge() {
        echo '<div class="badge"><img src="URL" style="width:175px;height:175px;"></div>';
        }
```

I have not had any luck in getting it to display, and am thinking that the 'woocommerce_template_product_description' maybe the problem - I'm sure if I am targeting the product description correctly. I think tabs are increasing the complexity of the solution.

Using the code below the image displays next to the product summary.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'badge', 25);
        function badge() {
        echo '<div class="badge"><img src="URL" style="width:175px;height:175px;"></div>';
        }
```

I would appreciate some help is solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

After much head scratching I think I might have figured it out. This code seems to work:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'magva_badge', 98 );
       function magva_badge( $tabs ) {

       $tabs['description']['callback'] = 'woo_custom_description_tab_content'; // Custom description callback

       return $tabs;
   }

    function woo_custom_description_tab_content() {
        woocommerce_product_description_tab(); echo '<div class="magva_badge"><img src="https://www.magva.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/made_in_ireland.png" style="width:175px;height:175px;"></div>';
       }
```